# showing $ch_T (T) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

$\def\ch{\operatorname{ch}}\def\diag{\operatorname{diag}}$
Let $v$ be a vector space with $T\colon V\to V$ linear. Let V have a basis consisting of eigenvectors of $T$. Show $\ch_T(T) = 0$ without using the CH theorem.

My attempt:

$\ch_T(x) = \det (xI - [T]_B)$, where $[T]_B = \diag(\lambda_1,... \lambda_n)$ with $\lambda_1,\ \ldots, \ \lambda_n$ eigenvalues of each eigenvector.

Where I am lost: if I plug in $T$ I get $\ch_T(T) = \det (TI - [T]_B)$, what is $TI$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** what is the value of $ch_T(T)(v)$ when $v$ is an eigenvector?

Comment: @moodkid I'm not sure could you tell me how I can find it?

Comment: **Hint:** write $P(T) = \prod (\lambda_i I - T)$. One of the factor of the product is such as $(\lambda_i I - T)v = 0$.